# Why do I get a "Value Cannot be Null" error on material.SetTexture?

Tags: unity, c#

Probably a really noob question, but:

I'm following this tutorial [here](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/) and, using the code in the tutorial, I'm getting an annoying error:
[image]

Here's the code in question, the error is referring to line 20 (highlighted in the comments):

```
public class RayTracingMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ComputeShader RayTracingShader;

    public Texture SkyboxTexture;

    private RenderTexture _target;

    private Camera _camera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    private void SetShaderParameters()
    {
        RayTracingShader.SetTexture(0, "_SkyboxTexture", SkyboxTexture); // <- Line 20 is here
        RayTracingShader.SetMatrix("_CameraToWorld", _camera.cameraToWorldMatrix);
        RayTracingShader.SetMatrix("_CameraInverseProjection", _camera.projectionMatrix.inverse);        
    }

    private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        Render(destination);
        SetShaderParameters();
    }

    private void Render(RenderTexture destination)
    {
        // Make sure we have a current render target
        InitRenderTexture();

        // Set the target and dispatch the compute shader
        RayTracingShader.SetTexture(0, "Result", _target);
        int threadGroupsX = Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.width / 8.0f);
        int threadGroupsY = Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.height / 8.0f);
        RayTracingShader.Dispatch(0, threadGroupsX, threadGroupsY, 1);

        // Blit the result texture to the screen
        Graphics.Blit(_target, destination);
    }

    private void InitRenderTexture()
    {
        if (_target == null || _target.width != Screen.width || _target.height != Screen.height)
        {
            // Release render texture if we already have one
            if (_target != null)
                _target.Release();

            // Get a render target for Ray Tracing
            _target = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0,
                RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);
            _target.enableRandomWrite = true;
            _target.Create();
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't see why it's telling me the value is null when I'm calling the name of an already defined Texture class. I have set the texture from the inspector. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136674/nullreferenceexception-in-unity); maybe it's relevant here.

Comment: Can you verify:1)  does the texture compare as equal to null just before you try to SetTexture? 2) Does FindKernel return a different index than the one you're using (0)?

Comment: @DMGregory How do I check if the texture is equal to null at a certain place in the program? Also, as far as I know I'm using just the one kernel, hence referencing kernel 0.

Comment: Why not simply `if(SkyboxTexture == null) Debug.LogError("It's null, yo!");`? Also: are you certain that Unity's systems assign the kernel the index zero in this case? It would make sense, but there are also reasons why it might not, so it's worth double-checking with `FindKernel` to be certain.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, thats helpful, I'll try that. Im very new to C#, and Unity scripting on the whole. I'm guessing I can do a similar thing with FindKernel? The tutorial I'm using said that it's kernel 0 because its the only one, but like you say, I'll check - Unity has been updated plenty since it was written.