# Unity Initializing class of a script not working

Tags: unity, c#

I have been trying to find a solution for the last couple of hours so please hear me out. At first I got a NullReferenceException, which I resolved(?) by initializing the class first (This is my problem! I can't seem to initialize my class sucessfully). However, here are my next errors. I tried using the `new` keyword, which resulted in `You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword`. Next I tried `GetComponent<>()`, which resulted in a `CS0120`, that I didn't know how to fix. The `AddComponent<>()`, resulted in a `CS0103` `The name AddComponent does not exist in the current context`. What I tried next was `GameObject.AddComponent<>()`, which threw a `CS0120`, and `gameObject.Addcomponent<>()` which threw a `CS0236`.

Here is my code for the class I am trying to initialize if it should be needed:

```
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour {
public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
public string[] sentences;
private int index;
public float typingSpeed;

public GameObject continueButton;

void Update() {
    if (textDisplay.text == sentences[index]) {
        continueButton.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public IEnumerator Type() {
    foreach (char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray()) {
      textDisplay.text += letter;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    }
}

public void NextSentence() {
    continueButton.SetActive(false);

    if (index < sentences.Length - 1) {
        index++;
        textDisplay.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
    } else {
        textDisplay.text = "";
        continueButton.SetActive(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is from where I tried to initialize:

```
public class Mace : MonoBehaviour {
//Dialogue dialogue = gameObject.AddComponent<Dialogue>();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider) {
    if (otherCollider.CompareTag("Player")) {
        StartCoroutine(dialogue.Type());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you're trying to put code into a field initializer that is not valid there. As your error messages are telling you, field initializers are not allowed to reference non-static members, because when they run, by definition, the instance they're running for hasn't finished initializing yet!

You have two main options ([which are already explained thoroughly here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136674/39518) — this is why it's important to read thoroughly when someone links you to an existing duplicate Q&A)

**1.** Make your reference `public` and populate it in the Unity Inspector interface before you run your game. Then the variable will be filled in by Unity's deserializer automatically when your object loads/spawns.

```
public class Mace : MonoBehaviour {

    // This adds a field you can set in the Inspector.
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    void Start() {
        if(dialogue == null)
            Debug.LogError("You forgot to populate the dialogue field before running!");
    }

    // ...the rest of your script goes here.

}
```

**2.** Fetch/add the component you need when this script "boots up," in Start or Awake:

```
public class Mace : MonoBehaviour {

    // We can leave this private if wiring it up ourselves.
    Dialogue _dialogue;

    void Awake() {
        // Create a new dialogue component attached
        // to the same object as this script, 
        // and cache a reference to it.
        _dialogue = AddComponent<Dialogue>();
    }

    // ...the rest of your script goes here.

}
```

Myself, if the script only makes sense when there's a specific dependency present, I like to make that dependency visible to Unity so it can enforce it for me at edit time, then at runtime I can just pick up a reference to the component I know will be there waiting for me;

```
// This attribute tells Unity to add a Dialogue
// component anytime I add a Mace component.
[RequireComponent(typeof(Dialogue))]
public class Mace : MonoBehaviour {

    Dialogue _dialogue;

    void Awake() {
        // Since the editor enforces our dependency,
        // we can be confident it's there to "Get"
        _dialogue = GetComponent<Dialogue>();
    }

    // ...the rest of your script goes here.

}
```