# NullReferenceException in Swipe Controller Script

Tags: unity, c#

I am Getting a Exception in My Swipe Controller Script name Dot.Here is the Code

```
using UnityEngine;

 public class Dot : MonoBehaviour
 {
private Vector2 firstTouchPosition;
private Vector2 finalTouchPosition;

public float swipeAngle =0;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    firstTouchPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
    finalTouchPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

 void OnMouseDown()
{
    firstTouchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Debug.Log(firstTouchPosition);
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    finalTouchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.Log(finalTouchPosition);
    CalculateAngle();
}

void CalculateAngle()
{
    swipeAngle = Mathf.Atan2(finalTouchPosition.y - firstTouchPosition.y, finalTouchPosition.x - firstTouchPosition.x)*180/Mathf.PI;
    Debug.Log(swipeAngle);
}  }
```

[image: This is Compiling Error I am Getting]

Please Tell ME What Im Doing Wrong.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint where the error is reported and see which object is null?

Comment: It looks like `Camera.main` is returning `null`. Double-check that you have a camera in your scene with the `MainCamera` tag to be returned by this method, and that this camera is enabled so `Camera.main` can find it. [This is explained in our existing go-to Q&A thread on NullReferenceExceptions in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136675/39518), so remember to search first to find your answers faster.

Comment: Thanks it work I mistakenly deleted my main camera and when I created back I forgot to give it the tag of Main camera.