# game object disappears when I add OnTriggerEnter script

Tags: unity, c#

I'm setting up collision detection for my enemy objects and projectile. When I add the detect collision script below, my enemy object just disappears. Projectile has the same detect collision script and also disappears.

I get this error code:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MoveForward.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MoveForward.cs:16)

This is a copy of my prefab settings for enemy object:

[image]

I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you

Detect Collision Script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {

  }

  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
  }

}
```

Move Forward Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveForward : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed = 20f;
  public GameObject Trump;
  public GameObject Player;
  private Rigidbody enemyRb;
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    enemyRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    this.transform.LookAt(Player.transform);


  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
   
    
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you the problem is in your MoveForward script. We can't help you if you don't show us that script. Please take the time to read through [past Q&A on solving null reference exception errors in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136674/39518) and apply the advice there to your case.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but don't forget to indicate which line is the line 16 responsible for the error! Here, it looks like your problem is covered by the "Accessing a GameObject that doesn't exist:" section of the past Q&A linked above.

Comment: Thank you, I took out the this.transform.LookAt line and I don't get the error anymore. Turns out my Player game object disappears on play, which is why I kept getting the Null error. Now to fix the disappearing gameobject.