# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlatformController.FixedUpdate ()

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

How do I fix it, I don't know how I fix it? Can anyone help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform posA, posB;
    public int Speed;
    Vector3 targetPos;

    control Control; 
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector3 moveDirection;

    private void awake()
    {
        Control = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<control>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetPos = posB.position;
        DirectionCalculate();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, posA.position) < 0.05f)
        {
            targetPos = posB.position;
            DirectionCalculate();
        }

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, posB.position) < 0.05f)
        {
            targetPos = posA.position;
            DirectionCalculate();
        }

        //transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, Speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = moveDirection * Speed;
    }
    
    void DirectionCalculate()
    {
        moveDirection = (targetPos - transform.position).normalized;
    }
  
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //collision.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
            Control.isOnPlatform = true;
            Control.platformRb = rb;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //collision.transform.SetParent(null);
            Control.isOnPlatform = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reverse your capital letter in your variable names for `control Control`. It makes the reading confusing, since normally uppercase stands for classes and lower one for variables, the same with `Speed`.

Comment: [Follow the debugging guidance here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136674/39518). You have only one reference type used in `FixedUpdate` and that's `rb`, so you know that variable has not been assigned. Checking the code that was supposed to assign it, we see it's in a method called `awake` with a lowercase a. Unity will only call the method `Awake` with an uppercase A (and generally in C#, method names are expected to start with an uppercase letter). So your initialization code is not getting run. Fix your typo.