# Raycast keeps giving the error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, c#

So I am trying to make a raycast shoot out whenever I click mouse0 or left click but whenever I do that it just pauses my gave and give me the error " object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm new to unity and coding in general so I'm not sure what I've done wrong with my code.

```cs
public class gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    int id;
    
    int enemyLayerMask;
    
    GameObject GameController;
    ItemDatabase database;

    Camera mainCam;

    void start()
    {
        GameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("GameController");
        database = GameController.GetComponent<ItemDatabase> ();
        mainCam = Camera.main;
        id = GetComponent<ItemId> ().ItemID;
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            shoot();
        }
    }

    void shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(mainCam.transform.position, mainCam.transform.forward, out hit, database.weapons [id].range))
        {
            
            if (hit.transform.tag == "enemy")
            {
                
                CharacterStates enemystats = hit.transform.GetComponent<CharacterStates> ();
                enemystats.TakeDamage (database.weapons [id].damage);
                Debug.Log (database.weapons [id].damage);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

with my code `mainCam` just refers to the camera in the scene.

`database` is a script that has the weapons damage range etc..

each weapon has an id to be able to find its specific damage range etc. that's what `database.weapons[id]` goes to.

`enemystats` is were I get confused because in the tutorial I used it just made that inside of the script and it seemed to be branching off of another script which is just for general stats for characters.

Comment: Code should be shared as text, never as an image. You should identify which line throws the error, and which object reference it's complaining about. Candidates here are `mainCam`, `database`, `database.weapons[id]`, and `enemyStats`, any of which could be `null`. I've linked this question to [past Q&A detailing how to troubleshoot this kind of error in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136674/nullreferenceexception-in-unity) - try to apply the advice there, and edit this question to show how you've tried applying those solutions if you still need help.

Comment: Did you try checking whether each of these variables was `null` before using it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing that is there somewhere I could look to learn?

Comment: In the link I gave you above, check out the line `if(collider != null)` for an example.